# file upload progress bar with paperclip on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paperclip

I need to show a progress bar for file uploads and i have no idea. Any help will be appreciated.

Application is on Heroku and files are on S3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use jQuery file upload which doesn't require flash, only javascript and is compatible with all browser (including IE6): https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I wrote the tutorial in the wiki and made a sample app here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Pic-upload---Crop-in-Ajax

Using both jQuery File Upload and Uploadify (on in each branch)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a blog post about using rails 4 with paperclip and uploadify.

http://vignesh.info/blog/rails-4-uploadify-paperclip/

Paperclip already supports aws api and files can be stored on S3. If you have plans of using dropbox take a look at this gem https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox